# Facebook Share + IMAGE + WINDOW SIZE + SYSTEMS

Tags: facebook, image, window, system, share

I am using the script - metioned below - for a facebook share button.  It works but there are 3 specific questions.

1. Is it necessary to use an image?  There is really no need for an image in this particular case - all I want is a description and a link.  If the the image object is omitted and the url is tested using the facebook debugger https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/, it reports a missing image.
2. When the share button is clicked a small rectangular window opens.  Is it possible to change that to a whole page instead of a small window?
3. I am using it now for a web share.  Is it safe to use the same script for ios, android as well?

Thanks!

Javascript + Meta Tags

```
        <HEAD>
        <script>
            function onClick(url) {
                FB.ui({
                    method: 'share',
                    href: 'https://www.your-url.com',
                });
            }

            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                FB.init({
                    appId      : 'APP_ID',
                    xfbml      : true,
                    version    : 'v2.3'
                });
            };

            (function(d, s, id){
                var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
                js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
        </script>

        <meta name="og:title" content="TITLE"/>
        <meta name="og:type" content="TYPE"/>
        <meta name="og:url" content="URL/"/>
        <meta name="og:image" content="IMAGE URL"/>
        <meta name="og:site_name" content="NAME"/>
        <meta name="og:description" content="DESCRIPTION"/>
```

And in the body:

```
            <script>
              window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                FB.init({
                  appId      : 'APP_ID HERE',
                  xfbml      : true,
                  version    : 'v2.5'
                });
              };

              (function(d, s, id){
                 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
                 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
                 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
               }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
            </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Is it necessary to use an image?
```

According to the specification of the [Open Graph Protocol](http://ogp.me/#metadata), `og:image` is a required attribute, so yes, you will need one. If you do not specify an image, social networks might auto-select one from the markup of your page.

```
When the share button is clicked a small rectangular window opens. 
Is it possible to change that to a whole page instead of a small window?
```

No.

```
I am using it now for a web share. Is it safe to use the same script for 
ios, android as well?
```

Yes, it should work with mobile browsers as well

Comment: Thank you very much, Björn Kaiser,  for your reply!